# Hybris extension addon conflict css

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I have an extension, similar to CyberSource.

The extension is necessary - extension " b2ccheckoutaddon " by which imports of all CSS files

Is there any way to not import these files?

I need to because some conflicts are occurring with CSS and break my screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you change those properties defined in b2ccheckoutaddon:

```
b2ccheckoutaddon.css.paths.desktop=/desktop/common/css/b2ccheckoutaddon.css;/desktop/common/css/checkoutContentPanel.css;/desktop/common/css/checkoutOrderDetails.css;/desktop/common/css/checkoutProgress.css
b2ccheckoutaddon.css.paths.mobile=/mobile/common/css/b2ccheckoutaddon.css
```

to

```
b2ccheckoutaddon.css.paths.desktop=
b2ccheckoutaddon.css.paths.mobile=
```

in local.properties